Cannot mount volume in Ignition | Permission issue | Ignition migration
I'm running ignition version 8.1.42 in AKS which describe following issue. The version 8.1.25 is running perfectly fine.

I found out that 8.1.25 is running as root user and after that update container is run as non-root user.
My deployment file looks like below. ref: https://forum.inductiveautomation.com/t/ignition-on-azure-kubernetes-service/68388
The issue is stated here: https://www.docs.inductiveautomation.com/docs/8.1/platform/docker-image
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ignition-deployment
  namespace: ignition-poc
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ignition-application
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ignition-application
    spec:
      # initContainers:
      # - name: seed-volume
      #   image: inductiveautomation/ignition:8.1.42
      #   resources:
      #     limits:
      #       memory: "256Mi"
      #       cpu: "1000m"
      #   command:
      #   - export IGNITION_UID=0
      #   - export IGNITION_GID=0
      #   - sh
      #   - -c
      #   - >
      #     if [ ! -f /data/.ignition-seed-complete ]; then
      #       touch /data/.ignition-seed-complete ;
      #       cp -dpR /usr/local/bin/ignition/data/* /data/ ;
      #     fi
      #   volumeMounts:
      #   - mountPath: /data
      #     name: ignition-data
      containers:
      - name: ignition
        image: inductiveautomation/ignition:8.1.42
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "2048Mi"
            cpu: "1000m"
        args:
        - -n
        - Ignition-k8s
        - -m
        - "2048"
        env:
        - name: ACCEPT_IGNITION_EULA
          value: "Y"
        - name: GATEWAY_ADMIN_USERNAME
          value: admin
        - name: GATEWAY_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          value: Test123
        - name: TZ
          value: “America/Chicago”
        - name: IGNITION_EDITION
          value: standard
        - name: IGNITION_UID
          value: "root"
        - name: IGNITION_GID
          value: "root"          
        ports:
        - name: ignition-http
          containerPort: 8088
        - name: ignition-https
          containerPort: 8043
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/local/bin/ignition/data
          name: ignition-data
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - health-check.sh
            - -t
            - "3"
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 3
      volumes:
      - name: ignition-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
         claimName: ignition-poc-pvc

I tried to change user to root or chown of files. But I cannot do that without root privilege.
Thanks in advance.

Yes, you are correct, I tried with 8.1.42 and getting the same error. The Docker documentation mentions that Ignition now runs as a non-root user for security reasons. Can you modify your deployment  by adding an initContainer to your deployment that changes the ownership of the volume to the non-root user before the main container starts to ensure that the non-root user used by Ignition ?

Got it, I was not having much idea on init-containers. So explored that and it seems now it will works,
Thanks :)

Good to know. Will post the same as answer

Below solutions works for me.
Run the ignition deployment with below config
  env:
    - name: IGNITION_UID
      value: "2003"
    - name: IGNITION_GID
      value: "2003"  

  securityContext:  
    runAsUser: 0
    runAsGroup: 0

Let it complete the process of migration, in my case it took 4-5 min. Check logs for more details.
Once above step is completed, delete the existing deployment and above mention config and try to deploy again.
This will not show any permission issue, hence we have migrated to newer version. Readiness probe will failed (try to change it's persmission).

Since Ignition 8.1.42 runs as a non-root user and you are facing permission issues when mounting volumes, the best approach is to use an initContainer to adjust the permissions of the mounted volume before the main Ignition container starts. Below is the deployment configuration that includes the initContainer to handle the permission changes.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ignition-deployment
  namespace: ignition-poc
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ignition-application
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ignition-application
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-permissions
        image: inductiveautomation/ignition:8.1.42
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/local/bin/ignition/data"]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/local/bin/ignition/data
          name: ignition-data
      containers:
      - name: ignition
        image: inductiveautomation/ignition:8.1.42
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "2048Mi"
            cpu: "1000m"
        args:
        - -n
        - Ignition-k8s
        - -m
        - "2048"
        env:
        - name: ACCEPT_IGNITION_EULA
          value: "Y"
        - name: GATEWAY_ADMIN_USERNAME
          value: admin
        - name: GATEWAY_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          value: Test123
        - name: TZ
          value: "America/Chicago"
        - name: IGNITION_EDITION
          value: standard
        ports:
        - name: ignition-http
          containerPort: 8088
        - name: ignition-https
          containerPort: 8043
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/local/bin/ignition/data
          name: ignition-data
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - health-check.sh
            - -t
            - "3"
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 3
      volumes:
      - name: ignition-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
         claimName: ignition-poc-pvc



as an additional step if you want you can also create a diagnostic pod named inspect-pvc running in the ignition-poc namespace for inspecting the contents/state of the Persistent PVC to verify the correct mounting of volumes and to ensure that the data or permissions within the volume are as expected.

Reference-
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/

It shows Below error:
Back-off restarting failed container init-permissions in pod ignition-deployment-6bdbfb5cbd-gzqcr_ignition-poc(2f3f8a2e-ec0f-4faf-b9cc-9efc3626984c). Volume is attach perfectly also verified by creating separate pod.

check the logs of the failing init-permissions container

The container shows error:
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 629: /usr/local/bin/ignition/data/init.properties: Permission denied
When we see the ownership of location  /usr/local/bin/ignition/data/ is ignition(UID: 2003) & ownership /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh is root.
As the docker is running in non-root I cannot change any permission of root user.
Let's me check some other approach.
IDK why it's working on your case.
